# Mow the lawn, cut the grass, mow the yard, cut the yard ...what is correct?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-usage

This weekend I mowed the yard. My neighbor says he cut the grass. Did I cut the grass, or maybe I mowed the lawn, or did I cut the yard?

When does one mow, and when does one cut? Is it grass, or yard, or lawn?

Comment: I cut my yard up the other day. But I mowed the grass down along with my friend.

Comment: In Australia we say "mow the lawn", but in Malaysia the literal translation from the local language is "cut the grass".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Mow the lawn", "cut the grass", and "mow the yard" are all basically describing the same thing, though I'd say "mow the yard" is more common in US English and the other two in British English.  The only one that sounds wrong is the fourth; I've not heard the phrase "cut the yard" used before.

I'd say you can *mow* and *cut* the grass, *mow* the yard, and *mow* the lawn.

Comment: If "mow the yard" is US usage, it's one I've not encountered before. In my experience, one cuts the grass, but mows the lawn. No, it doesn't make sense, but such is idiom.

Comment: In British English, nobody would expect a yard to have grass.

Comment: @Martha -- "mow the grass" isn't unheard of, but it's kind of redundant (what *else* would you mow?)  @Henry, what *do* you have in your yard? (Or is "yard" in American English exactly a "garden" in British English, where a "yard" might be a "square" or a "quad"?)

Comment: @Malvolio: In the UK, a yard is a paved area, most often found in institutions such as schools.

Comment: @Colin Fine -- for a primary school, that's called a "playground".  For colleges and such, it's a "quad" (although usually it would have grass or other pleasant landscaping rather than paving, on the theory that college students stroll rather than destroying things).  For any other institution, it's the "grounds" (and is *never* paved, on purely aesthetic grounds). (All examples in US English, of course.  Why can't the English teach their children how to speak?)

Comment: @Colin Fine: You must get out more and meet the poor folk in densely-packed terraces. Many of them have *back yards* (although they tend to drop the space now, following US usage). IMHO a back yard is what you have instead of a garden if it's too small to include even a bit of lawn.

Comment: "Mow the yard" is pretty common in the Southwestern US, at least. Nobody says "cut the yard." This is a very good answer.

Comment: @Malvolio: all those words are used for schools in the UK too (though colleges are not schools, and the grounds are the wider expanse of land that the institution is set in). But "yard" in British usage means an enclosed paved area, which might be a playground or a quad - or the back yard of a terrace house, as FumbleFingers reminds me.

Comment: My Dad always tells me to go "mow the yard"! Though, I think "mow the lawn" is most common and logical?

Comment: @Malvolio: "mow the grass" may be redundant, but "mow" is a transitive verb that to me sounds funny without an object. I wouldn't say *"I'm going to mow this morning."* And all the reasonable objects you can use -- the grass, the yard, the lawn -- are equally redundant.

Comment: @Malvolio: why, the meadow of course! http://www.smart-central.com/mow.htm

Comment: I have to admit, I've used the phrase, "Cut the yard" as well as the others.

Comment: @Peter If you just say you are going to mow, how do I know what you will mow, how should I know whether you will mow the lawn or mow the meadow?

Comment: -1 Because the answer from z7sg Ѫ seems to clearly prove this answer to be incorrect. If I'm wrong, please explain.

Comment: ...or just churlishly vote down without bothering to attempt to clarify, despite the mission statement of this site.

Comment: @Colin: In AmE, a canonical 'yard' is grassy.

Answer (score 11):

In a [survey](http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_100.html) of 10553 respondents in the United States, the favoured expressions were:

```
mow the lawn         66.79%
cut the grass        18.38%
mow the grass         5.75%
cut the lawn          0.64%
other                 8.43%
```

Geographically, most areas favoured *mow the lawn*

[image: mow the lawn]

but *cut the grass* was preferred in a few localities, mostly southern states.

[image: cut the grass]

Comment: Oh my goodness, where do you find information for such an obscure question?

Comment: @kpsfire I remembered the survey from a question I asked about *positive anymore*.  Amazing the minutiae that serious linguists devote themselves to... I do love it though!

Comment: +1 for an excellent source. And this explains why *cut the grass* and *mow the lawn* are the only two that sound right to me, a lifelong Mid-Atlantic resident.

Comment: these maps remind me of https://xkcd.com/1138/

Answer (score 0):

Mow means (or usually means) specifically [to cut down (grass) with a machine](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mow). You could say "this weekend I did the mowing", with the understanding that you cut grass with a tool of some description.

As touched on above, *lawn* is simply [regularly mown grass](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lawn?rskey=pP4BBY&result=1). You could expect a yard (or similar) to be regularly tended to, and thus contain lawn. In my experience saying *cut the grass* carries the connotation that what's there could *hardly* be referred to as *lawn* (possibly with a haughty raise of the nose).

Answer (score 0):

"Mowing the lawn" is universally understood in American parlance. It refers to the action of cutting wide swaths or a large area of grass (the lawn) using a machine. "Cutting the grass" is also well-understood, and refers to the same action, optionally with the additional steps of trimming and edging (which also cut the grass, but are more precise than the connotation of "mowing" indicates).

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, a lawn would generally be a well-kept area of domestic grass. You'd probably not describe an overgrown or partly bare area of domestic grass as a lawn except with a note or irony.

"Mow" can have a rather agricultural feel to it, so "mow the grass" is perhaps more what a farmer might do.